# What is the best way to minimize parents destroy a Windows clean install after few days?

Tags: windows, security

Every time the same, probably you already know.
I'm asking here the best procedure in order to minimze the possibility that a non-expert user could fill the system with spyware, virus and all related stuff making it unusable after few days.
I know that the question could result not so professional and silly, but I strongly believe that is an hot topic for a lot of people, because is not easy to protect a system from its owner.

I do not think that adblock is enough, but probably the approach needs additional restrictions. Could you please make any suggestions?

Comment: They need Windows for a specific purpose.

Comment: Don't restrict yourself to technical means, there's a human factor you may be able to improve. Educate, even some elders are willing to learn. The power of ignorance is huge so help them to be as little ignorant as possible. If they tell you they don't want to learn, tough luck then; but never assume in advance they are unable to learn. Ask. Some will happily support any solution that lets them stay in their comfort zone without learning new things; but some will be very glad if you show them you believe they are smart enough to learn, and if you give them your time and attention as a tutor.

Answer (score 1):

Beside a good adblocker and a good antivirus-antimalware, a few other advices:

- Do not grant your parents administrative rights, create specific standard user accounts (assuming you can help when they need to install software, even remotely via Teamviewer)
- Use a DNS service already filtering some bad IP addresses, like Opendns in example (https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227986707-Understanding-Malware-and-how-OpenDNS-helps)
- Install and a disk imaging tool allowing you to rollback to a previous C: drive status like Veeam Agent (https://www.veeam.com/windows-endpoint-server-backup-free.html). You can schedule a daily "forever incremental" backup, make sure to keep backup at least for the last 14 days, so you can restore a good working status even a few days after the damage (maybe your parents will not immediately report an issue to you). You will need a separate partition or disk (better).
- Do not install unneeded software requesting frequent security updates (do your parents really needs Java? Can they use Chrome or Edge built-in PDF support instead of installing Acrobat?)
- Use online services for email and documents when possible (Gmail with built-in Office-like features in example) to minimize impact of unfortunate events affecting local files.
- Make sure Windows Update runs automatically

Comment: You can also use DeepFreeze so the computer reverts every time it is rebooted.